# Why is my Tauri app performance worse after bundling?

Tags: tauri

I have a [Tauri](https://tauri.app/) app created with `npm create tauri-app@latest` and the svelte template. The app works perfectly in a browser and with `npm run tauri dev`, but after being bundled has terrible, and I mean unusable, performance.

The main issue seems to be playing an embedded video. The video (±100mb) barely loads and after it does only plays a couple of frames per second. The mp4 video file is stored in the client-side "static files" (`/public`) and displayed in a normal `<video/>` element,

This is on a Mac (Intel) with the latest version of Tauri, etc. (at time of this writing).

Since it works smoothly in development, my best guess is this is a bundle configuration issue. Does anyone know what the problem might be here?

Edit: I've opened up the project on a windows machine and build a windows version that works just fine.

Comment: Are you still running it all locally when bundled? If so, what web server are you using?

Comment: @Phil No web server. All files, including the media/videos, are bundled with the app.

Comment: Sorry, I got caught up on the Svelte bit and was thinking it's a web app